# Javascript: How do I get the sum without concatantion?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, .net

How can I stop javascript from concatenating my two values that I'm trying to get the sum of.

I did a search and I found `parseInt(String s)` to turn string to int. But when I tried the attempt below it failed.

Attempted this, but it failed.

```
$total = "£" + ( parseInt($amount2) +  parseInt($rent));
```

Code that messes up

```
            $total = "£" + ($amount2 + $rent);
```

Full function

```
 function update(slider, val) {
            //changed. Now, directly take value from ui.value. if not set (initial, will use current value.)
            var $amount = slider == 1 ? val : $("#amount").val();
            var $duration = slider == 2 ? val : $("#duration").val();
            var $rent = $("#MonthlyRent").val();
            var $amount2 = $amount.replace('%', '');

            /* commented
            $amount = $( "#slider" ).slider( "value" );
            $duration = $( "#slider2" ).slider( "value" );
             */
            $total = "£" + ($amount2 + $rent);
            $("#amount").val($amount);
            $("#amount-label").text($amount);
            $("#duration").val($duration);
            $("#duration-label").text($duration);
            $("#total").val($total);
            $("#total-label").text($total);

            $('#slider a').html('<label><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span> ' + $amount + ' <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></label>');
            $('#slider2 a').html('<label><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span> ' + $duration + ' <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></label>');
        }
```

Comment: for your title, it's javascript, not java ...

Comment: considering its amounts, I would suggest using `parseFloat()` instead

Comment: Please define 'failed'. What happens and what is it you want to happen?

Comment: What is the value of `$amount2` after you capture it here `$amount.replace('%', '');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can sum the numbers using Number();

```
    $1="0.56";
    $2="0.65";
    var a=Number($1)+Number($2);
    alert("$"+a);
```

[Example jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RQ4f7/)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try the following :

```
$total = parseInt($amount2) +  parseInt($rent);
$total = "£" + $total;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `$amount2` and `$rent` hold numbers:-

```
$total = "£" + ($amount2 - - $rent);
```

The `- -` is shorthand for `string to integer converter` and also adding later.

For later calculations, use `isNaN` to be sure that the result is a number.

Example:

```
if(!isNaN($total)){
    // do other calculations
}
else{
    // show error message or do nothing
}
```